# REST - Fetch newly created resource without hibernate

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I am using Spring MVC and **NamedParameterJdbcOperations** .

I am making a rest call to create an object and I want to return this newly created object.

How can then I return the newly created object regardless of the database used?

I am not using hibernate. In hibernate the persisted object can be returned immediately .But I want to achieve this without hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **NamedParameterJdbcOperations**'s update method to get the key of newly created object and then fetched the object using this key.

To get the key -

```
GeneratedKeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

namedParameterJdbcOperations.update(sql,sqlParameterSource,holder);
int key = holder.getKey().intValue();
```